# nodemon watches onjy JavaScript files not TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, nodemon

`nodemon` should be started on debugging in Visual Studio Code and watch TypeScript. On any TypeScript changes, it should re-compile them using `ts-node`. I'm struggling with many issues here. The currently most important one is that `nodemon` watches only the generated `.js`files, but not the original `.ts`ones - although I explicit let them watch typescript.

`launch.json`

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "nodemon",
    "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.ts",
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/dist/*.js"
    ],
    "restart": true,
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "args": [
        "--inspect-brk",
        "-x 'echo hello123'"
    ],
    "timeout": 30000
}
```

When I start debugging, "hello123" is printed. After saving `index.ts` nothing happens. If the generated `dist/index.js` script is saved by hand, it shows "hello123" too.

Of course, this is only to isolate the issue. In fact, I want to run a npm script to re-compile typescript like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "ts-node": "ts-node --inspect-brk index.ts"
}
```

But the main problem is: *Why* does `nodemon`only watches the generated js-files instead of their typescript ones? Seems like this is caused by `outFiles` attribute. Without it's not working, it shows an error that corresponding js files cant' be found.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure nodemon to watch typescript files as it does not watch `.ts` by default

Add `nodemon.json` file in root with the following content, and then just run nodemon:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", ".git", "node_modules"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./index.ts"
}
```

or run nodemon as

```
nodemon --watch 'workspace/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' index.ts
```

I hope this will work.