# How to watch and re-run TypeScript on change?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I have a very simple application written in TypeScript:

**src/index.ts**

```
import * as http from "http";

const server = http.createServer((request, response) =>
{
    response.end("Hello, World");
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Then my TypeScript configuration:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // Output options
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es2016"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./build",
    }
}
```

I can build my code using `npx tsc` and then run it using `node ./build/index.js`, and upon visiting http://localhost:3000 in a browser I see the message "Hello, World" -- all good so far

Now using `npx tsc -w` I can watch the files to see if they change and re-compile them when this happens. This command run "forever" (until stopped) so it prevents me from running `node ./output/index.js` in the same terminal. Using multiple terminal windows or a terminal multiplexer I can pretty trivially run `node ./output/index.js`, but this file won't get re-run if my code is re-compiled. This means that if I change the string "Hello, World" to "Hello, Steven" I won't see the change until I manually stop my server and restart it

Is there a way to watch my TypeScript files like this **and** run the output so that the output is stopped and re-run when my code changes?

Comment: Closely related: [*How to auto-reload files in Node.js?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972242/how-to-auto-reload-files-in-node-js)

Comment: Closely related: [*How to watch and reload ts-node when TypeScript files change*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979489/how-to-watch-and-reload-ts-node-when-typescript-files-change) and [*nodemon watches onjy JavaScript files not TypeScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565505/nodemon-watches-onjy-javascript-files-not-typescript)

Comment: I won't vote to close because I have a dupehammer and don't want to use it (if I did, I'd point to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565505/nodemon-watches-onjy-javascript-files-not-typescript)), but it looks like the answer is `nodemon` + `ts-node` with a bit of config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run `tsc` and [`nodemon`](https://nodemon.io) at the same time:

```sh
npx tsc -w & npx nodemon build
```

or use nodemon with [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#readme):

```sh
npx nodemon -x ts-node -e ts src
# to run even if there are TS errors:
npx nodemon -x 'ts-node --log-error' -e ts src
```

or just use [`ts-node-dev`](https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev#readme):

```sh
npx ts-node-dev src
```